# Methods for plotting $\sin(1/x)$ near the origin

Tags: plotting

Goal 1 is to produce a nice plot of the function $\sin\frac{1}{x}$. The insight of plot experts and visualization experts is welcome.

The plot will eventually be used to show 
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\sin\frac{1}{x}
$$
does not exist (excluding the interval function). This entails plotting sequences which converge to different values. Dots will be use

After a few attempts, let's go back and start with the simplest case:

`Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 0.1}, Frame -> True]`

[image: sin 1/x]

Here is one sequence of points which converges to $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$:

[image: dots]

Goal 2 (optional) is to find a light version that can be sent to pdf. My naive efforts of increasing resolution create an enormous file which is difficult to use in applications like LaTeX.

Goal 3 (optional), the dots. I can live with them, but posters are so often surprising, it seems unwise to exclude their ideas.

**Update**

From @A.G.

[image: ag]

Comment: use `PlotPoints` to improve the quality.

Comment: @george2079: Tried that. The hope is that somebody can do better.

Comment: you might do a `LogLinearPlot`. Its not really clear what sort of answer you are seeking.

Comment: How about `Plot[Sin[1/x], {x, 1/1000, 0.1}, Frame -> True, PlotPoints -> 500, 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[.0005]]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something you may find satisfactory:

```
a = .002; b = .1;
Show[
 Plot[Sin[1/x], {x, a, b}, Frame -> True, PlotPoints -> 1000, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[.0005]],
 ListPlot[{x, 1/2} /. Solve[Sin[1/x] == 1/2 && a < x < b, x], 
  PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

The pdf is 82KB and the exported jpg (400 dpi) is 911KB. Should be OK with $\LaTeX$

[image]

Comment: Alternatively: `Plot[Sin[1/x], {x, 0.002, 0.1}, Frame -> True, Mesh -> {{1/2}}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.0092], Red], PlotPoints -> 1000, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.0005]]`

Comment: @A.G.: +1 for solving for the dots instead of computing them hand!